# Performing regex extraction with apply() on pandas dataframe column uses result of first row for all rows

Tags: python, regex, dataframe

I have a column of time zone strings in a `Pandas DateFrame` where each string entry is a variation on the following:

```
'Local Time Zone (America/Chicago (CST) offset -21600)'
```

I am trying to extract the numeric offset (listed in seconds) at the end of the string with an `apply` call:

```
df['minuteOffset'] = df.timezone.apply(lambda x: int(re.match('.*?offset (-?[0-9]*)\\)', a).group(1)))
```

However, when I then look at the data frame, I see that first value -21600 carried forward for all rows even though other rows have other values. **How can I correctly extract the regex on a per row basis to generate a new column and why is the above failing?**

Comment: Have you used the variable 'a' in the regex when you actually meant to use 'x'?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```
In [85]: In [82]: df
Out[85]:
   id                                               timezone
0   1  Local Time Zone (America/Chicago (CST) offset -21600)
1   2    Local Time Zone (Kiev/Ukraine (EEST) offset +10800)

In [86]: df['minuteOffset'] = df.timezone.str.replace(r'.*offset\s+([\+\-\d+]+)\)', r'\1').astype(int)/60

In [87]: df
Out[87]:
   id                                               timezone  minuteOffset
0   1  Local Time Zone (America/Chicago (CST) offset -21600)        -360.0
1   2    Local Time Zone (Kiev/Ukraine (EEST) offset +10800)         180.0
```

Comment: @helloB, did it help?